# WCF sending parameters in a list future proof?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am building a really quick prototype to prove a concept, I have several WCF methods and number of parameters are more then 10 for each method and there is a strong feeling that they might increase in future.

Would it be future proof to send all parameters in a list instead ?

As parameters are either Int or string, This is what I am proposing (lets just forget OOP principles as it's a prototype)

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetData/?pList={pList}")]
void GetData(List<Object> pList);
```

**In other words, what is considered best practice when sending large number of parameters through WCF ?**

Comment: You could accept a `DataContextParameters` or something alike as well, i.e. a custom class with your parameters. The class definition would be easy enough to change, and IIRC WCF simply ignores missing properties when deserializing.

Comment: @Patrick - beat me to it. :) I was going to propose the same thing

Comment: @Patrick I also thought about that, but because parameters are so random the only name I could think of this is method's name itself or random - which is why i thought List would be more suitable

Comment: Or maybe an array this way I don't need to change object if i add any new parameter

Comment: I don't believe there is any "best practice" for this. You are free to do as you please, and since you already seem to have made up your mind for one solution, why not go for that and see how far it takes you?